# How to create bare repository with pack-refs?

Tags: git, bare

I need to create bare repository with `package-refs` files. Command `git init --bare` create bare repository without `pack-refs` files. What I have to do?

Comment: If you mean `.git/packed-refs`: (1) why do you care? (2) a packed refs file will only exist when there are some references to pack; a new empty repository has no objects and hence no references to those nonexistent objects.

Comment: (1) I need them (2) So how I create this references?

Comment: What do you need them for?

Comment: References are a general term for things like branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, `refs/replace` items, and so on. For those to exist, you must have some objects—usually, commits with files—in your repository.

Comment: I would rephrase the question: "How to prepare an fresh repo so a subsequent fetch will store refs directly as a packed-refs file, skipping the intermediate step of creating thousands of ref files and then `git pack-refs --all` ?" Or: "How to select packed-refs as the default backend ref store for a repo?"

Answer (score 0):

packed-refs files would only happen once:

- you have added some files and make some commits
- a [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) is done (which calls [`git repack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack))

An initial *empty* (bare or not) repository would therefore understandably do *not* have any packed files.

Comment: I believe the question seeks to create a repo where all refs are stored in packed format, without the need to `git gc`. An empty repo into which a large code base is fetched for the first time could end up with thousands of files in refs/, and there is a need for them to be stored in packed format from the beginning.

Comment: @JaredoMills I agree, and  I don't know if this is directly possible though.